# How to automatically send email to users after registering with Firebase Auth (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, angular2-forms

How can I automatically send email verification to user after an account has been created. I have this code so far.

```
            export class addContentComponent {
                add: FormGroup;
                constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
                    this.add = this.fb.group({
                       emailaddress: ['', Validators.required],
                        password: ['', Validators.required],
                              });   };
              emailsent = '';
              submitadd() { 
        const emailaddress = this.add.emailaddress.value;
        const password = this.add.password.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();
       const usertoverify = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailaddress, password)
                }

    **This is where i am confused**

            usertoverify.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
               this.emailsent = 'verification email has now been sent to ' + emailaddress;
        }, function(error) {
          // An error happened.
        });



            }
```

I have tried to use this code but it did not work
and help please?

**Meanwhile this is my html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitadd()"class="ui form" [formGroup]="add" novalidate>
 <input type="text" class="text-muted-signature" [formControl]="add.controls['emailaddress']" placeholder="Email" required>

 <input type="text" class="text-muted-signature" [formControl]="add.controls['password']"  placeholder="Password">

  <p>
<button  [disabled]="!add.valid" type="submit">add it!</button>
                                            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a template you can send email for newly registered users. Looking at the [Create custom email action handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) page, there's only 3 modes that we can send emails to

> - `resetPassword`
> - `recoverEmail`
> - `verifyEmail`

Which is also evident on the Firebase Console.